# Azure ARM Template - Key Vault Username & Password ID Variables?

Tags: json, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to concatenate the `id` path of the Key Vault URL within a variable? At the moment I have `adminUsername` and `adminPassword` parameters in the `parameters.json` file and the `id` fully typed out. However, I can fill out the `id` based on known information so makes the deployment easier. Below is my `parameters.json` file as is (with the important info taken out):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": {
        "adminUsername": {
          "reference": {
            "keyVault": {
              "id": "/subscriptions/<SubID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<KV>"
            },
            "secretName": "LocalAdminUsername"
          }
        },
        "adminPassword": {
          "reference": {
            "keyVault": {
              "id": "/subscriptions/<SubID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<KV>"
            },
            "secretName": "LocalAdminPassword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

It is the `id` where I want to include variables - possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify static values inside a parameter file. However, you can use a nested deployment to dynamically generate the KeyVault resource ID (example below).

In a nutshell;

1. Define parameters for parts of the resource identifier
2. Use template functions to assign defaults where possible
3. Use `concat()` to construct the identifier in a variable
4. Use a nested deployment to refer to the key vault using the variable.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "kvSubscriptionId": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[subscription().id]"
    },
    "kvResourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]"
    },
    "kvResourceName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "kv-resource-name"
    }
  },
  "functions": [],
  "variables": {
    "kvResourceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('kvSubscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('kvResourceGroupName'), '/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/', parameters('kvResourceName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
      "name": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          "parameters": {
            "adminUsername": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "resources": [...]
        }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "adminUsername": {
          "reference": {
            "keyVault": {
              "id": "[variables('kvResourceId')]"
            },
            "secretName": "LocalAdminUserName"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This technique is documented here: [Reference secrets with dynamic ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli#reference-secrets-with-dynamic-id).